# ms access 2010 vba excel application match not allowing excel to close completely

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I am using excel to create a pivot table through access and I have come into an issue where excel is not completely closing at the end of my code (it is still showing in Task Manager).  To troubleshoot this, I commented out my entire code and started uncomenting it line by line until it replicated the issue.

I now know that my `.Match` statement is the culprate, but I am not sure how to correct it.  I have tried using `Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` and `Excel.Application.Match` but still get the same result. I know the first `.Match` statement is in an `If IsError` statement, but I have isolated to specificly the `.Match` statement.

When I end the process through Task Manager and run my code again, I get error 462 "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable."

here is my code, thanks for the help.

```
Sub exceltest()
'Reference to MS Excel Library and to DAO or ACEDAO
Dim oRS As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oWC As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRange As Excel.Range
Dim oTable As Excel.PivotTable
Dim oField As Excel.PivotField
Dim z As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pf As Excel.PivotField
Dim ctl As Control
Dim rpt As Report
Dim LAATotalRange As Excel.Range
Dim LAARange As Excel.Range
Dim LAANBRange As Excel.Range
Dim LAAWBRange As Excel.Range
Dim LUSTotalRange As Excel.Range
Dim LUSRange As Excel.Range
Dim LUSNBRange As Excel.Range
Dim LUSWBRange As Excel.Range
Dim GTotalRange As Excel.Range


Set oXL = New Excel.Application
oXL.Visible = False
Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
Set oWS = oWB.Sheets(1)
Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblRONData")

oWS.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset oRS

   For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1
        oWS.Cells(1, i + 1) = oRS.Fields(i).Name
   Next i

'create pivot table

oWS.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Set oTable = oWS.PivotTableWizard

Set oField = oTable.PivotFields("Metal")
oField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set oField = oTable.PivotFields("Type")
oField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set oField = oTable.PivotFields("Sub Fleet")
oField.Orientation = xlRowField

Set oField = oTable.PivotFields("Day")
oField.Orientation = xlColumnField

Set oField = oTable.PivotFields("LAA NB")
oField.Orientation = xlDataField
oField.Function = xlCount

'format pivot table

Set oWC = oWB.Sheets("Sheet4")
Set oWS2 = oWB.Sheets("Sheet2")

oWS2.Cells(1, 1) = "TRUE"
oWS2.Cells(2, 1) = "LAA"
oWS2.Cells(3, 1) = "LUS"
oWS2.Cells(4, 1) = "LAA TOTAL"
oWS2.Cells(5, 1) = "LUS TOTAL"
oWS2.Cells(6, 1) = "NB TOTAL"
oWS2.Cells(7, 1) = "WB TOTAL"
oWS2.Cells(8, 1) = "GRAND TOTAL"


z = oWC.Cells(2, 4).End(xlToRight).Column
y = oWC.Cells(2, z).End(xlDown).Row
w = z - 1

sc1 = RGB(255, 197, 197) ' LUS NB
sc2 = RGB(255, 91, 91)   ' LUS WB
sc3 = RGB(209, 246, 255) ' LAA NB
sc4 = RGB(0, 173, 214)   ' LAA WB


If IsError(Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(oWS2.Cells(2, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)) = False Then
'    LAARow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(2, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)
'    LAATOTALRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(4, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)
'        Set LAATotalRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LAATOTALRow, 1), oWC.Cells(LAATOTALRow, z))
'            LAATotalRange.Font.Bold = True
'            LAATotalRange.Font.Size = 12
'        Set LAARange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LAARow, 2), oWC.Cells(LAATOTALRow, 2))
'            If IsError(Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(6, 1).Value, LAARange, 0)) = False Then
'                LAANBRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(6, 1).Value, LAARange, 0) + 2
'                Set LAANBRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LAANBRow, 2), oWC.Cells(LAANBRow, z))
'                LAANBRange.Interior.Color = sc3
 '               LAANBRange.Font.Bold = True
'                LAANBRange.Font.Size = 11
'            End If
'            If IsError(Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(7, 1).Value, LAARange, 0)) = False Then
'                LAAWBRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(7, 1).Value, LAARange, 0) + 2
'                Set LAAWBRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LAAWBRow, 2), oWC.Cells(LAAWBRow, z))
'                LAAWBRange.Interior.Color = sc4
'                LAAWBRange.Font.Bold = True
'                LAAWBRange.Font.Size = 11
'            End If
End If

'If IsError(Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(3, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)) = False Then
'    LUSRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(3, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)
'    LUSTOTALRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(5, 1).Value, oWC.Columns(1), 0)
'        Set LUSTotalRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LUSTOTALRow, 1), oWC.Cells(LUSTOTALRow, z))
'            LUSTotalRange.Font.Bold = True
 '           LUSTotalRange.Font.Size = 12
 '       Set LUSRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LUSRow, 2), oWC.Cells(LUSTOTALRow, 2))
'            If IsError(Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(6, 1).Value, LUSRange, 0)) = False Then
 '               LUSNBRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(6, 1).Value, LUSRange, 0) + LAATOTALRow
'                Set LUSNBRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LUSNBRow, 2), oWC.Cells(LUSNBRow, z))
'                LUSNBRange.Interior.Color = sc1
'                LUSNBRange.Font.Bold = True
'                LUSNBRange.Font.Size = 11
'            End If
'            If IsError(Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(7, 1).Value, LUSRange, 0)) = False Then
'                LUSWBRow = Excel.Application.Match(oWS2.Cells(7, 1).Value, LUSRange, 0) + LAATOTALRow
'                Set LUSWBRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(LUSWBRow, 2), oWC.Cells(LUSWBRow, z))
'                LUSWBRange.Interior.Color = sc2
 '               LUSWBRangeFont.Bold = True
 '               LUSWBRange.Font.Size = 11
 '           End If
'End If

'Set GTotalRange = oWC.Range(oWC.Cells(y, 1), oWC.Cells(y, z))

'With GTotalRange
'     .Font.Bold = True
'     .Font.Size = 13
'     .Interior.Color = RGB(143, 202, 140)
'End With


 '   With oWC
 '       .Cells.Font.Name = "Arial monospaced for SAP"
 '       .Cells.Font.Size = 10
  '      .Range(.Columns(4), .Columns(z)).ColumnWidth = 6.3
  '      .Range(.Columns(4), .Columns(z)).WrapText = True
  '       Set oRange = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(y, w))
  '      .PivotTables(1).ShowDrillIndicators = False
  '      .PivotTables(1).PivotCache.Refresh
   '     .PivotTables(1).MergeLabels = True
  '      .Range(.Columns(4), .Columns(z)).EntireColumn.AutoFit
  '      .Rows(1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
  '      .Columns(z).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

  '  End With




'Set pt = oWC.PivotTables(1)

'  For Each pf In pt.PivotFields
'      pf.EnableItemSelection = False
'  Next


'oRange.CurrentRegion.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
'DoCmd.OpenReport ReportName:="rptRONData", View:=acViewDesign

'For Each ctl In Reports!rptRONData
'ctl.Name = "ctlDelPic"
'DeleteReportControl "rptRONData", "ctlDelPic"
'Next

'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPaste

'For Each ctl In Reports!rptRONData
'    ctl.Name = "ctlNewData"
'        With Reports!rptRONData.ctlNewData
'            .SizeMode = acOLESizeStretch
'            .Width = 23040
'        End With
'Next

'DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptRONData", acSaveYes


oWB.Close False
'oXL.Visible = True

Set oWB = Nothing
Set oWS = Nothing
Set oRS = Nothing
Set oTable = Nothing
Set oField = Nothing
Set oWC = Nothing
Set oWS2 = Nothing
Set LAATotalRange = Nothing
Set LAARange = Nothing
Set LAANBRange = Nothing
Set LAAWBRange = Nothing
Set LUSTotalRange = Nothing
Set LUSRange = Nothing
Set LUSNBRange = Nothing
Set LUSWBRange = Nothing
Set GTotalRange = Nothing
Set oRange = Nothing
Set pt = Nothing

oXL.Quit

Set oXL = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: oXL.WorksheetFunction

Comment: OMG, I have no idea how long I worked on this yesterday.  I can't believe it was that simple.  Thank you!